# Docker image NGINX not exposing : site cannot be reached

Tags: nginx, docker

**1.** I was using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-nginx-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide to get a nginx webserver image to run and used the commands

> docker run -p 8888:80 nginx
>
> docker run -p 80:80 nginx

I guess two or more containers got up and running but when I open localhost:8888 it shows the site cannot be reached.

I have also used [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/hello-world/) to try and expose something on my browser. It showed the same problem too.

**2.** One more question, when I run more containers with the same image file, the terminal shows nothing as console and doesn't even terminate i.e, return to the the dollar sign . So I would be stuck and forced to open another terminal. Is there some trick concept I'm missing here.

**Please note** I have installed docker on windows and used docker quick start terminal for the above.

Comment: Not getting `Connection refused` is a good first step. At least you know you are talking to something, probably `nginx`? Might be worth ssh'ing into your container and check the nginx.conf file on /etc/nginx. Make sure the server name is `localhost` or paste it here to share with us.

Comment: I'm sorry , I hadnt been more clear before the error message i see on the page was : "This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect."

Comment: lets do this 1 by 1. @Codex I would recommend stopping all containers you got there and only start the one with `80:80`. once you got it running do a `docker ps`. Make sure only 1 container is running and it has something like this `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp`. This means that your all ip addresses of your localhost:80 is mapped to the container's port 80.

Comment: :) :) Yes, it was done. and still I see the same error on the webpage : localhost:80 , the container says the same thing uve mentioned and it up and running

Comment: But I did not check nginx config file , is there a way to ssh the container without boot2docker ?!!

Comment: I usually do `docker ps -a` - to get the container id. Then `docker -i -t [container_id] /bin/bash`. This should be enough to get you in. FYI you shouldn't have to specify the `:80` bit to access the page because by default `http` means port 80

Comment: Silly question here. @Codex did you tried accessing `http://localhost` on the browser or `http://localhost:80`?

Comment: Either way its redirecting to http://localhost/ so pretty smart browser i guess :P . I'm installing vim editor in the container. I'll change the conf file and see what happens ... :) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I was running it on VM on windows which happens with docker .

So in one of the [beginner tutorials](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/usingdocker/) it was mentioned that the port is forwarded to this VM port not on the windows port. (Just read the note below the hello world! browser image)

So you have to find the ip address of your VM OS and paste it in the browser along with the port number.

Comment: How did you find the ip address of your VM OS?

Answer (score 6):

For me in Windows instead of pointing to localhost i used the resulted ip of running the command:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Answer (score 3):

You should run:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:80 nginx

docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

`-d` parameter, Run container in background and print container ID

Comment: Thanks for explaining the flag, that worked ! :) Can you also guide me on what could be the problem for the 1st question ?!

Comment: after run `docker run -p 8888:80 nginx` to make sure docker container `nginx` is running or not, to chec that using command : `docker ps`

Comment: Make my answer is the correct answer if it would correct

Comment: Yeah I did check the list of running containers, its showing up in the list but not on the browser , its not exposed on the browser, that is the main problem. I'm not able to see any output.

Comment: `telnet localhost 8888` run it on dos(command line). make sure port 8888 is open.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command to get the ip:

```bash
docker-machine ip default
```

and then used `http:\\ip:port\` to access nginx

Answer (score 1):

In my case i tried this commands to debug what is wrong

```
➜ docker exec -it <container_name> ps aux | grep nginx
➜ docker exec -it <container_name> cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
➜ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name>
```

When i check this

```
 docker exec -it crazy_bose netstat -tuln

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

The netstat output indicates that Nginx is listening on port 80 inside the container.
But i configured nginx to run on port 5000 with IntelliJ IDEA Docker service and the container might not have been started with the correct port binding.to check that i used this, here command with **incorrect output**

```
docker inspect <container_name> | grep "5000/tcp"

                "5000/tcp": [
                "5000/tcp": {},
                "5000/tcp": [
```

then i stop that container and started new one with this command

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 5000:80 --name crazy_bose nginx
```

finally it works ---Welcome to nginx!
Commands are useful to debug, hope that it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone who arrives here following the book - "Deploy Containers on AWS
> With EC2, ECS, and EKS"

Please know that the flow which works is as follows -

```
PS C:\Users\nrajora> docker build --tag awsnginx .\gitouch\dockers\
[+] Building 0.2s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazonlinux:2                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/amazonlinux:2                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/2] RUN amazon-linux-extras install nginx1                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:fe1a3a2493bb8fdc6e1838d07ce450217cb9b6d95b8459b986c180c8bc4a53c7                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/awsnginx                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
PS C:\Users\nrajora> docker run -d -p 8081:80 nginx
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
e1acddbe380c: Pull complete
e21006f71c6f: Pull complete
f3341cc17e58: Pull complete
2a53fa598ee2: Pull complete
12455f71a9b5: Pull complete
b86f2ba62d17: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4d4d96ac750af48c6a551d757c1cbfc071692309b491b70b2b8976e102dd3fef
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
9e8dc2373283770c7f6418e9377885cf3b1a3cb02858d939d0ddd09331458fc2
```

Now your Docker will build, will deploy and will be reachable at the url shown below - http://localhost:8081/

> Welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is
> successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
> Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

In case you are wondering about dockerfile -
Here it is.

```
FROM amazonlinux:2
RUN amazon-linux-extras install nginx1
EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Tested for Latest docker version as follows on 20 Aug 2021 -

```
PS C:\Users\nrajora> docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.4
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 12:00:56 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux
```