# Cannot access custom NGINX container via the public internet, only on the localhost

Tags: docker, nginx

I am building a custom docker image to run nginx and host a website on a VM of mine at a public cloud provider.

Note: mysite.com is a replacement for my real domain/test site.

Infrastructure:

This is all running on a Ubuntu 22.10 Vultr VM, iptables has been turned off to troubleshoot.

If I stop the docker container and start the native local nginx service on the machine the site content does load over the public internet mysite.com:80.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx

RUN rm /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html

COPY index.html /var/www/html/index.html
COPY /pictures/ /var/www/html/pictures/
COPY mysite.conf /etc/sites-enabled/mysite.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My sites nginx config is as such, `mysite.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/html;
}
```

Docker image building and running as follows:

```
docker build -t mysite_nginx .
docker run -p 80:80 -d mysite_nginx
```

Now when I `curl localhost` I am given the index.html as expected, however if I go to mysite.com via my local laptop browser (which is a live delegated public domain) I get the following error:

```
mysite.com refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I was under the impression with 80:80 mapped, when I access the IP/hostname from the public net I would get the index.html inside of the container. The site can be viewed from the host running the container, but not from the public internet.

Any idea what I may be missing?

I see many similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of which are mapping ports 80:80 and answer my specific issue.

For example:

[NGINX docker container cannot be accessed in the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395385/nginx-docker-container-cannot-be-accessed-in-the-web-browser) (different port mapping)

[Docker image NGINX not exposing : site cannot be reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432469/docker-image-nginx-not-exposing-site-cannot-be-reached) (different port mapping, not getting "connection refused" as I am)

The answers I do see appear to suggest the following setup should work without issue. If needed I can add more context if I know what would help.

Comment: You dont mention anything about the infrastructure thats hosting this container and how your domain points to it. First guess would be some sort of firewall blocking the traffic. Windows firewall, Linux IP tables, cloud provider security group, cloud provider ACL to name just a few

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added the following extra details:

This is all running on a Ubuntu 22.10 Vultr VM, iptables has been turned off to troubleshoot.

If I stop the docker container and start the native local nginx service on the machine the site content does load over the public internet mysite.com:80.

Comment: when you run the docker container what does `sudo netstat -anltp | grep :80` show you? When i run nginx in a docker conatiner on almalinx with port 80 mapped I get `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      869996/docker-proxy`. are you running the docker command with sudo or is your user part of the docker group. to run things on ports less than 1024 you normally need to run as sudo

Comment: netstat output:

`# sudo netstat -plant | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      234346/docker-proxy 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      234350/docker-proxy`

I reran my docker run command as root as well, same result will not load over the public net over http://ip:80

Not sure if anything here is a redflag

Comment: Network wise it looks fine. Port 80 is bound and will listen on any network interface of the vm. Do you have iptables active on the vm. I have seen instances where people of iptables active and an INPUT rule which allows port 80 but missing a FORWARD rule for docker.

Comment: I have tried to remove iptables as a possible issue by disabling ufw:

# service ufw stop

Also worth noting if I stop the container and start the nginx service on the host itself, I am able to load the site.